# Function call on_guild_role_update does not get called when a role is updated

Tags: python, discord

My bot is in 3 servers currently and the function `on_guild_role_update` doesn't get called anywhere and never. The bot does have admin permissions so it should see everything that would've been restricted. I have the `@bot.event` decorator before the `on_ready` function and another one after it and before the `on_guild_role_update`.
It looks like this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    #on_ready code

@bot.event
async def on_guild_role_update(before, after):
    print("1") #Included this just to see If the function even executes. It doesn't
    if before.name != after.name:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Role " + before.name + " renamed to " + after.name + ".")
        embed.set_author(name="Role update")
        await bot.message.send(bot.get_channel(str(channelid)), embed=embed)
```

Am I missing something or does this not work anymore? I've checked the docs but besides [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_guild_role_update), I didn't find anything relevant.

Comment: Are your other events firing?  Try adding a `print(discord.__version__)` to check your version number.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Yeah, I also have `on_message`, `on_command_error` and `on_ready` which all work perfectly. I checked the version and It threw me _0.16.12_, is it perhaps outdated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an old version of discord.py.  You can get the latest by running

```
python -m pip install -U discord.py
```

with the python interpreter you run your bot with.  The 1.0 release introduced several breaking changes, so you'll have to use the [migration guide](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html) to change your code to the new interfaces.